# Eclipse is letting me export my project with errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I set `android:minSdkVersion="7"` while my code had `GridLayout`s (which were added in api level 14).

Now, unless I click on my gridlayout in the java file, make a change, then save it - eclipse won't say that there is an error and I can export the project and create an apk from it.

I would really like eclipse to be able to detect when a method etc has been added in an api higher than your minimum. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Sometimes, eclipse is behaving like that. Kindly restart it and reset your ADB.

Comment: have you enabled lint warning. i guess lint should warn you about this. http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks

Comment: @Raghunandan I think so, I've seen yellow lines under some of my code that have the word lint in them. Other than that I don't know what lint is sorry

Comment: @JwalinShah I restarted it, it did not work. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Lint options are under preferences - Window->Preferences->Android. In order for Lint to check every time you have to enable the "Run full error check when exporting app and abort if fatal errors are found"
Also you might have to see if Lint is enabled for the project you are exporting. In order to check it right click on the project and go to Properties -> Android Lint Preferences

[image: Lint preferences]